# Why can't I assign a string to a ReadOnlySpan using .Net Framework 4.8?

Tags: c#, .net-4.8

I am trying to make use of `ReadOnlySpan`. I am trying to convert a guid variable to `ReadOnlySpan` like this:

```
ReadOnlySpan<char> newGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

But I get compile error

> Cannot implicitly convert type `string` to `System.ReadOnlySpan<char>`

The `ReadOnlySpan` type comes from the System.Memory nuget package. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you want a `ReadOnlySpan<string>` and not `ReadOnlySpan<char>`?

Comment: @Luke i even tried ReadOnlySpan<char>

Comment: What version of .NET are you working with?

Comment: @Luke i am using 4.8

Comment: `ReadOnlySpan` doesn't exist in .Net Framework 4.8

Comment: @gunr2171 if it doesnt exist then how can i get it in intellisense?

Comment: You forgot to mention that you're using the System.Memory nuget package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ReadOnlySpan` (whether you get from the [System.Memory package](https://github.com/dotnet/corert/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/ReadOnlySpan.cs#L194-L203) or from the runtime) only has [implicit casts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.readonlyspan-1.op_implicit?view=net-6.0) for arrays. So you need to turn your string into an array of chars first.

```
ReadOnlySpan<char> newGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToCharArray();
```

In newer versions of .Net, like .Net 6, the `string` class [has an implicit cast to `ReadOnlySpan<char>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.op_implicit?view=net-6.0), alleviating the need to turn your string into an array first.

Comment: It worked with ToCharArray but i dont see System.Memory package being added in my project

Comment: Trust me, ReadOnlySpan [doesn't exist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.readonlyspan-1?view=net-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.8) in the regular 4.8 runtime. The only way you can get it is through the System.Memory nuget pacakge. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/memory-and-spans/ "For earlier frameworks, Span<T> and Memory<T> are available in the System.Memory NuGet package.") You can test for yourself by making an empty 4.8 console app, then adding System.Memory. Most likely your app has the nuget package deep in the dependency tree.

Answer (score 1):

As gunr says, there is no implicit cast from `string` to `ReadOnlySpan<char>`.
However, you can also use `AsSpan()` directly:

```
ReadOnlySpan<char> newGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().AsSpan();
```